# Another SandCastle problem: Reports missing Summary and Param, but they aren't missing

Tags: sandcastle

I'm using SandCastle Help File Builder in Visual Studio 2022.  After generating the help files from my C# XML Comments file, the generated documentation shows red comments about "missing summary" and/or "missing param", but they aren't really missing.

Here is a picture of one of my documented methods.

[Documented method with errors reported](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WTrET.png)

However, as can be seen below, my XML Comments file does show that method with a  section and a  section.

[Summary and param present](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ej8CJ.png)

The XML comments are correct, so I was expecting to see them documented in the generated HTML help file.  Also, the XML Comments file and the assembly file are included in the Documentation Sources.

Comment: Please add your code and error messages as text, not as pictures.

Comment: It's hard to give the true display of error messages and/or code in text only.  But, regardless, I've decided to use Doxygen to generate my documentation instead of Sandcastle.  It doesn't give me any problems.